# Faulty error response from WooCommerce Rest API Coupon Delete

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api, http-delete, coupon

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new coupon (or use the id of an existing one).
2. Delete it with an http request to `DELETE /wp-json/wc/v3/coupons/<id>` as per the [WooCommerce Rest Api Documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#delete-a-coupon).
   The resulting response always seems to be

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_delete",
  "message": "The shop_coupon cannot be deleted.",
  "data": {
    "status": 500
  }
}
```

Even though the checking the coupons status, which is now `trash`, shows that the deletion was successful.

Did not find any record of this problem posted online.  I tracked the problem to the Woo source code.

`class-wc-rest-crud-controller.php`

```
$object->delete();
$result = 'trash' === $object->get_status();
...
if ( ! $result ) {
    /* translators: %s: post type */
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_rest_cannot_delete', sprintf( __( 'The %s cannot be deleted.', 'woocommerce' ), $this->post_type ), array( 'status' => 500 ) );
}
```

The above code looks ok, it’s reasonable that the status of the object should change to trash upon a successful call to $object->delete(); .  However,  looking closer at the code in `WC_Coupon` `delete()`

```
wp_trash_post( $id );
do_action( 'woocommerce_trash_coupon', $id );
```

The trashing of the coupon is accomplished with a global function which is independent of the WC_Coupon object that is saved in $object.  Therefore the line from above $result = 'trash' === $object->get_status(); will always come back false.

Comment: Yep, I get the same behaviour - good analysis :)